# What would be the fastest way to find the maximum of all possible distances between any pair of points in a list.

Tags: python

I have a list `l` which holds `n` number of points. Each element in the list is a point with x-coordinate and y-coordinate. I am trying to find out the quickest way with which I can find the maximum of all possible distances between the elements in the list `l`.

To be precise Let the list `l` be

```
l = [(1,2),(5,3),(6,9)]
```

If

```
d((1,2),(5,3)) = 1,  
d((5,3),(6,9)) = 2,  
d((6,9),(1,2)) = 5
```

where `d` is my distance function, my solution is `5` that is maximum of all possible distances between any pair of points in the list.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do try something before asking someone else for the code directly. Add some code that you have tried, the errors you got if any. Stackoverflow does not provide you with complete code

Comment: It looks like you have the pseudocode worked out. You will want to take the distance function d^2 = (x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 for all x,y.

Comment: I am not expecting the code bro. A suggestion should be fine for me. I can try coding it and extend the query if I face any issues. Thank You! @Bhargav Rao

Comment: Finding the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) would probably be a good start.

Comment: @Kevin I will try working on it. The concept seems interesting.

Comment: @Shawn: The question contains no code, pseudo- or otherwise (except for some assignment statements).

Comment: @martineau, foolishly, i was attempting to be constructive and positive in my encouragement. **sighs**

Comment: what is your distance function?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use numpy and scipy? [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) seems to do what you want. And by experience, it also solves it extremely quickly even if there are hundreds of thousands of points, which would basically choke pure python.

Find the Euclidean distances between four 2-D coordinates:

```
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance
>>> coords = [(35.0456, -85.2672),
...           (35.1174, -89.9711),
...           (35.9728, -83.9422),
...           (36.1667, -86.7833)]
>>> dists = distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean')
>>> dists
array([[ 0.    ,  4.7044,  1.6172,  1.8856],
       [ 4.7044,  0.    ,  6.0893,  3.3561],
       [ 1.6172,  6.0893,  0.    ,  2.8477],
       [ 1.8856,  3.3561,  2.8477,  0.    ]])
```

To find the maximum distance, you can just use numpy's `max` function.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.max(dists)
6.089281104531147
```

So in your case:

```
>>> l = [(1,2),(5,3),(6,9)]
>>> np.max(distance.cdist(l, l, "euclidean"))
8.602325267042626
```

It is not 5, but I'm guessing you gave arbitrary values for the result of `d`?

Answer (score 0):

To get all combinations of the points you can use itertools

```
for p0, p1 in itertools.combinations(list, 2):
    print( d(p0,p1) )
```

will print you all (three is this case) distances.  Finding the max left as an exercise...

Comment: I don't think O(n^2) would be considered efficient

Comment: Efficient in development time, ease of maintenance and clarity of the code.

Comment: Yeah, OP never defined which eval criteria were going to be used to determine efficiency.

Comment: @ShawnMehan,  *What would be the fastest way to find the maximum of all possible distances between any pair of points in a list.*

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you that it's O(n^2). I'm just saying that the OP never really stated what kind of efficiency that they were looking for. Fastest way could be the smallest number of characters that one has to type into a homework assignment that one couldn't be arsed doing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> max(((i,j,dist(i,j)) for i,j in itertools.combinations(l, 2)), key=lambda x:x[2])
((5, 3), (6, 9), 13)
```