# Deriving boolean expressions from hand drawn logic gate diagrams with python OpenCv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

[image: Input hand drawn logic gate diagram]

Using tensorflow I identified all the gates, letters and nodes.
When identifying all above components, it draws a rectangle box around each component.

Therefore, in the following array it contains list of all the components detected. Each list is in the following order.

```
Name of component 

X, Y coordinates of top  left corner of rectangle 

X, Y coordinates of right bottom of rectangle
```

Nodes (Black Points) are used to indicate a bridge over a line without crossing.

Array of all above components.

```
labels =[['NODE',(1002.9702758789062, 896.4686675071716), (1220.212585389614, 1067.1142654418945)], ['NODE',(1032.444071739912, 635.7160077095032),(1211.6839590370655, 763.4382424354553)],['M', (57.093908578157425,607.6229677200317),(311.9765570014715,833.807623386383)],['NODE', (344.5295810997486, 806.3690414428711), (501.8982524871826, 930.6454839706421)], ['Z', (21.986433800309896, 1327.9791088104248), (266.36098374426365, 1565.158670425415)], ['OR', (476.0066536962986, 574.401759147644), (918.3125713765621, 1177.1423168182373)], ['NODE', (333.50814148783684, 1058.0092916488647), (497.6142471432686, 1202.9034795761108)], ['K', (37.06201596558094, 870.0414619445801), (311.77860628068447, 1105.8665227890015)], ['AND', (665.9987451732159, 1227.940999031067), (1062.7052736580372, 1594.6843948364258)],['AND', (1373.9987451732159, 204.940999031067), (1703.7052736580372, 612.6843948364258)], ['NOT', (694.2882044911385, 260.5083291530609), (1027.812717139721, 450.35294365882874)], ['XOR', (2027.6711627840996, 593.0362477302551), (2457.9011510014534, 1093.9836854934692)], ['J', (85.69029207900167, 253.8458535671234), (334.48535946011543, 456.5887498855591)], ['OUTPUT', (2657.3825285434723, 670.8418045043945), (2929.8974316120148, 975.4852895736694)]]
```

Then, using line detection algorithm I identified all the 17 lines connecting each component.
[image: Image of all the lines (17 pink color lines).]
All above 17 lines take as a list of arrays, and those lines are not in a correct order and each line has 2 end points.

```
lines = [[(60, 1502), (787, 1467)], [(125, 1031), (691, 988)], [(128, 772), (685, 758)], [(131, 336),(709,347)], [(927,350),(1455, 348)],  [(400, 1361), (792, 1369)], [(834, 843), (2343, 939)], [(915, 1430), (1119, 1424)], [(1125, 468), (1453, 470)],  [(1587, 399), (1911, 405)], [(1884, 755), (2245, 814)],[(2372, 831), (2918, 859)], [(1891, 397), (1901, 767)],  [(1138, 457), (1128, 738)], [(441, 738), (421, 903)], [(1125, 946), (1101, 1437)], [(420, 1098), (408, 1373)]]
```

[image: Lines explain diagram]
When connecting those lines, it is must to consider following scenario.
[image: Scenario to consider when connecting lines]
It means nodes are used to indicate a bridge without crossing lines.

**M is an input to the AND gate and (M.Z) is an input to the other AND gate.**

So how can I generate the following Boolean Expression using above 2 arrays and above scenario? **This should be a function that works for all logic gates.**

It can be assumed that image is always going to read from left to right.
[image]

Comment: Interesting problem, although it might be a bit too broad. [Here](https://github.com/dan-masek/logic_chart_analyzer) is my first working (and really hacked up) version that gives me as result `OUTPUT = (((M AND Z) AND (NOT J)) XOR (M OR K))` | The idea is basically to create a graph representing your data (using the bounding boxes and line intersections) and then have the graph generate the result expression.

Comment: Thank you for your support. But when I tried with different data set (logic_data.py) , it does not give the answer and it ends up with more exceptions. So can you please  go trough with those exceptions and I need a detailed description of the logic you used to derive the Boolean Expression.

Comment: new data set link.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QyP705VIXaNmEP5GhtmFmEmaZTKS-_ca/view?usp=sharing

Comment: error : 
raise RuntimeError("Nothing connected")
RuntimeError: Nothing connected

Comment: Oh, I see, this one has NAND gates too, I didn't expect those, so it didn't recognise those labels as gates. Next, too strict threshold for finding the second node in a node pair. And then an issue due to removing lines from a list -- i'll replace that with a boolean flag signifying whether it has already been used. Watch the repo, i'll be committing updates there as I play with it. I'll also start writing up some notes on the implementation, because it will take a fair amount of work to put it all together.

Comment: Thank you for your big support.Actually I want to get the output for any of the given data set.What are the limitations you put in to the logic while you are coding and what are the assumptions you come up with the diagram(input image). And also can I know that , is it must to keep gates perfectly one above or down or can it be placed in anywhere without considering nearest gates?

Comment: input image for the new data set is [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/16usr_F7iG0KIH9FgmMaIkHKUZblSETYO/view?usp=sharing ]

Comment: Thanks, yeah I though it looked something like that ([rendering of the data you provided](https://i.imgur.com/oQvbUf7.png)). The gates don't have to be aligned. Lines should be close to horizontal or vertical (slightly crooked is ok, but no diagonals). Nodes should be aligned vertically... two very close pairs could confuse things. | The more datasets to test with, the better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187890/discussion-between-dan-masek-and-pasan-sumanaratne).