# How to detect lines in noisy line images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv

I generate noisy images with certain lines in them, like this one:

[image: Generated image]

I'm trying to detect the lines using OpenCV, but something is going wrong.

Here's my code so far, including the code to generate the noisy images.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def draw_random_lines(img, w, n):
    for i in range(n):
        point1 = (np.random.randint(low = 0, high = w), np.random.randint(low = 0, high = w))
        point2 = (np.random.randint(low = 0, high = w), np.random.randint(low = 0, high = w))
        cv2.line(img,point1,point2,(255,0,0),5)
    x = y = 0
    while(y<w):
        while(x<w):
            if(np.any(img[x, y] != 0)):
                if(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100) < 60):
                    img[x, y] = [255, 255, 255] 
                else:
                    img[x, y] = [0, 0, 0]
            else:
                if(np.random.randint(low=0, high=100) < 95):
                    img[x, y] = [255, 255, 255] 
                else:
                    img[x, y] = [0, 0, 0]
            x+=1
        x=0
        y+=1
    return img

w = 512
img = np.zeros((w,w,3), np.uint8)
img = draw_random_lines(img, w, 5)
cv2.imshow("Original", img)
cv2.imwrite("alo.png", img)
img = cv2.imread("alo.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for line in lines:
    for rho,theta in line:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)


cv2.imshow("Detectada", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And here are the results I'm getting (very wrong):

[image: Wrong Results]

So, how can I properly detect the lines in these noisy images?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since OpenCV's Hough transform implementations look for white pixels on black background, the first important step for finding the lines is to invert your noisy images.

Slight [median blurring](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) will further help to get rid of the noise, thus improving the performance of the Hough transform.

For my suggested solution, I also used the [`HoughLinesP`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga8618180a5948286384e3b7ca02f6feeb) method instead of [`HoughLines`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a). (From my experience, you'll get "better" results.)

So, here's my code snippet:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read input
img = cv2.imread('images/K9YLm.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Initialize output
out = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Median blurring to get rid of the noise; invert image
img = 255 - cv2.medianBlur(img, 3)

# Detect and draw lines
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, 1, np.pi/180, 10, minLineLength=50, maxLineGap=30)
for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        cv2.line(out, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('out', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output `out` looks like this:

[image: Output]

Due to the usage of `HoughLinesP`, you get a quite large set of (smaller) lines. One would need to setup a kind of "grouping" of similar lines. (Or, maybe one could just draw the red lines on a separate image, and re-run the line detection.)

Hope that helps!

Comment: “maybe one could just draw the red lines on a separate image, and re-run the line detection” This seems quite redundant to me. If OpenCV gives access to the parameter space, a bit of smoothing there and a better way of detecting local maxima would go a long way to fix the multiple detections per line problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I haven't properly searched before, but there seems to be [this promising Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531074/). I'll test their solution(s) next week - and then keep that piece of code nearby.