# How to merge lines after HoughLinesP in opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, hough-transform

I have this code I am trying to wrap my  head around that detect plant Crop-row using segmentation and HoughLine method.

I understand the segmentation and the HoughLineP part very well. But I get stuck on **how to merge the lines outputted** from the HoughLineP method.

My Question are

1. Why would we want to merge the lines detected by HoughlinesP method
2. What are the possible way to merge this line.. a link to any material would be greatly appreciated

I stumble on a similar question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531074/how-to-merge-lines-after-houghlinesp) but there wasn't much explanation just bunch of code

without the merging part here is the output of the HoughlineP on the test image
[test_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4utDS.png)

**HoughLineP method**

```
def draw_lines(image,mask):
    mask = mask*255
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(5,5),1)
    mask = cv2.Canny(mask.astype(np.uint8),80,255)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(mask,1,np.pi / 180,threshold=50,
                        minLineLength=50,maxLineGap=250)
    lines = np.squeeze(lines, axis=1)
    m_lines = merge_lines(lines)
    for line in m_lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line.astype(int)
        cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    
    return image
```

#merge lines that are near to each other based on distance

```
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as P
def merge_lines(lines):
    clusters =  []
    idx = []
    total_lines = len(lines)
    if total_lines < 30:
        distance_threshold = 20
    elif total_lines <75:
        distance_threshold = 15
    elif total_lines<120:
        distance_threshold = 10
    else:
        distance_threshold = 7
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = line
        if [x1,y1,x2,y2] in idx:
            continue
        parameters = P.polyfit((x1, x2),(y1, y2), 1)
        slope = parameters[0]#(y2-y1)/(x2-x1+0.001)
        intercept = parameters[1]#((y2+y1) - slope *(x2+x1))/2
        a = -slope
        b = 1
        c = -intercept
        d = np.sqrt(a**2+b**2)
    cluster = [line]
    for d_line in lines[i+1:]:
        x,y,xo,yo= d_line
        mid_x = (x+xo)/2
        mid_y = (y+yo)/2
        distance = np.abs(a*mid_x+b*mid_y+c)/d
        if distance < distance_threshold:
            cluster.append(d_line)
            idx.append(d_line.tolist())
    clusters.append(np.array(cluster))
    merged_lines = [np.mean(cluster, axis=0) for cluster in clusters]
    print(clusters)
    print(merged_lines)
    return merged_lines
```

I understand how the slope and intercept was obtain in the merging function.. but the rest of the code I don't understand.

Comment: Is that question substantially different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708420/how-to-merge-nearby-lines-in-houghlinep-opencv)? If not, please consider self deleting one of them - most likely this one, since the other has comments.

Comment: @HansHirse it is different